# How to query the firebase database to fetch specific data?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

```
    {
  "todo" : {
    "Kujbghnkj04t56-" : {
      "id" : 1,
      "tags" : [ {
        "name" : "Italy"
      }, {
        "name" : "Australia"
      } ],
      "username" : "ABC"
    },
    "oPikoieew9oR-" : {
      "id" : 2,
      "tags" : [ {
        "name" : "Switzerland"
      } ],
      "username" : "XYZ"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to search in Firebase according to tags name. My code is:

```
var tagRef = new Firebase(FURL+'/todo');
    var tagCollection = $firebaseArray(tagRef);
    tagCollection.$ref().orderByChild("tags").equalTo("Australia").once("value", function(dataSnapshot){

   // code
});`
```

How can I get the snapshot of all data containing tag name as "Australia"

Comment: Your data structure makes it hard to easily filter using Firebase methods. You could just get every "todo" elements and filter the returned object in JS.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've edited the question according to your suggestion.

Comment: @PierreC Thanks for the suggestion, As I am having large volume of data, and using Pagination to fetch the data. We have tried filtering in the JS, but it filtered only paginated data, whereas we want to get the data based on tags as we have different Todo categories. Can you please suggest, how to implement it.